# Css: Why not use ID, another reason than tightly coupled

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a page where there's a  tag with an `id`, but a normal css class, like this one:

```
<div id='stack_overflow_example' class='title'> ... </div>
```

As everybody knows, this `id` have to be unique on that page, and I'm using it only to easily find it under css (could be used for ajax requests, for example, but this is not the case).

Reading about css locators (selectors), I found that I should not use IDs as css selectors, because this would tightly couple my css code with my html code.

Alright, I agree. But the option is to put a unique css class on that tag, and then use it on css code.

Why this option is not as tightly coupled as the first one?

Could anybody give any other reason than what I just thought: "Because on this second option, you can reuse the 'unique' css on other 'unique' tags too."

**EDITED**: Thinking about performance reason, my friend just thought (and I agreed):

- Using 'id' tag, the 'search' would go through all html code until find first use of the id, and then stop, because 'id' is `unique`
- Using 'unique class', the 'search' would go through all html code until EOF, because many elements could have that 'unique class'

Isn't it, on the end of the edge, a performance glitch making option 1 sound better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply one unique ID to **any one** element in each page. It doesn't matter *which* element has the ID as long as only one has it per page. There is no such rule for classes. Hence the coupling issues you're referring to (i.e. the CSS has a very rigid assumption that the element with a certain ID serves the same presentation and purpose across any HTML pages it's applied to).

Honestly I wouldn't really care about coupling (**EDIT:** or performance) issues so much. If I have an ID and I wish to apply styles *only* to that ID, I select by that ID. If the element shares that class with other elements and I want to apply styles to all elements with that class, I select by that class.

Comment: @Gabriel L. Oliveira: Performance doesn't really matter here either. HTML and CSS are about semantics and separation of concerns (but not *that* much about coupling/reusability), not performance.

Comment: @BoltClock thank you for answer. I got your point, and think that reasons round by both your and @kekekela answers on this page

Comment: @gabriel BoltClock in on the money here imo regarding not caring so much about performance...in the context of a web app with latency etc I think it would have to be a very very edge case for your css selectors to impact the user experience...if speed is your issue I've got to think 99.9999999999% of the time you're going to be optimizing somewhere else other than your css (its been 100% for me but if I say 100% I wll have too many people outlining that case where I am wrong :)

Comment: @kekekela Yeah, I understood it. This type of performance glitch would be on the bottom of the list, when thinking about performance optimization on web pages, right? :) Thank you. I just came on stackoverflow to ask this because it was burning my mind thinking about how much does it impact on performance, and here I can find better minds than mine to answer things like this :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are understanding it more or less correctly.  While imo there are situations where using an ID in a css selector is the right thing to do, the advantage of a class is not only that it can apply to more than one element on the page, but also that **you can have more than one class per element** which makes them easier to reuse.  (Imagine a case where I want to reuse some style rules that are currently being applied via an ID selector, however the element that I want to apply these to already is getting a set of style rules from another ID selector...can't give that element two IDs.  With classes, you won't run into this)

Comment: thank you for answer. I got your point, and think that reasons round by both your and @BoltClock answers on this page

Comment: @Gabriel "Can you have a look at my edit?" yeah, what you wrote there makes sense but you're getting into browser implementation details that I honestly don't have knowledge of...from personal experience I've never seen a performance hit from doing it one way over the other.  (not saying there isn't one, but if there is it is not generally noticeable)